# Regular Expression Repeating Pattern delimited by comma

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a regular expression of the following in Javascript:

```
/\w{1,}\s*\w{1,}/
```

This checks if a string has atleast two words greater than 1 character each.

Ex-

```
asd fgh - Valid  
a b d dfd - Valid  
xscxs - Invalid
```

I now have a new requirement that I have tried to implement, but cannot get right.

New requirement: Be able to have a comma separated list of the same type of input as before. Cannot end with a comma. Each item must be valid per the rules above.
If there are no comma then also its valid.
Also all characters are alphabets and no numbers/special characters

```
Valid:  HOH vfdffd,dsfds dfgd,UIU fgfd  
Valid:  JOI JOIO  
Invalid:  QASW fgdfg,  
Invalid:  sdfds,1234 dfgdfg  
Invalid:  JKJ,ABCD
```

Comment: Try [`^\w+(\s\w+)+(,\s*\w+\s\w+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gCz1n8/1)

Comment: could there be a space near comma, like `HOH vfdffd, dsfds dfgd ,UIU fgfd` ? would it be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may specify the pattern for the first requirement as `[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)+` to match 1+ letters chars and then match 1+ sequences of a whitespace + one or more word chars, and then just repeat the pattern inside another group with a comma:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)+(?:,[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)+)*$/i
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h4hbCF/2) (all `\s` replaced with spaces in the demo since the input is one multiline string).

If multiple spaces are allowed, replace `\s` with `\s+`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ letter
- `(?:\s[a-z]+)+`  - 1 or more sequences of (i.e. a space is obligatory)

  - `\s` - a whitespace (add `+` to match 1 or more occrurrences)
  - `[a-z]+` - 1+ letters
- `(?:,[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)+)*` - zero or more sequences (i.e. a comma is optional) of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `(?:\s[a-z]+)+` - see above
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: *Also all characters are alphabets and no numbers*

Comment: Ok, `\w` should be replaced with `[a-zA-Z]` or `[^\W\d_]`

Answer (score 0):

```
.regex(/^(?:(?![0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})(?:(?:\b\,)(?![0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})*$/)

Explanation:

(?:\b\,) -> Match with a , at the beginning of the string only if its preceded by a word boundary
(?:(?![0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}) -> Match a string with letter and digits only if dont have 4 digits ow 4 letters
```